# Windows Service not Retrieving data due to Activator.CreateInstance()

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I have an issue in my Windows Service Application, I have a scenario where I need to fetch a file path using a DLL(provided by the Client). For the purpose of faster debugging I have created a Console Application where the following code worked fine

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(System.Security.Principal.PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal)


_objAoApplication = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("AOLib6.Application"))

_strAoLastCompany = _objAoApplication.GetLastCompanyFile
```

But when I created the same as a Window Service `_strAoLastCompany` is getting an Empty String which is not desired.

Can anyone suggest me how do i get started